# Train, eval, and test in Tensorflow Object Detection API (TFOD TF2)

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection, object-detection-api, single-shot-detector

im new in TFOD API,
Im used to work with classification task, so little bit confuse with detection especially TFOD API.
1.which type of data that loss is calculated while training? is it eval? or Just data train?
2. is there any eval and test in TFOD terms?

I already success to train and eval, but i dont see any data test being used